# Two user accounts for one SVN repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

My setup is VisualSVN Server, and I am using VisualSVN on the client.

I have one repository.

Two people will use this computer, both using the same Windows user account.

Due to it being two different people, we need to use two different svn accounts when committing. Is this possible? I can only "switch" between svn accounts if I clear the saved authentication data in TortoiseSVN and relogin, but I was wondering if there was a better way around it?

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way?

Comment: make a second windows account. it will make life easier for everybody. Windows supports "Switch user" which leaves the first user logged on. so all open programs can stay open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable svn's authentication storage by putting an

```
store-auth-creds = no
```

To the **%APPDATA%\subversion\config** file

Then subversion will always asks you for a password in tortoisesvn you should uncheck to save authentication data.

Beside the problematic always login approach, I second Filip De Vos and recomend you to set up a second user account on same machine or a second machine with second user account.